# Image colorization using autoencoder - Maximum compression point

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am building a model for autoencoder. I have a dataset of images(256x256) in LAB color space.

But i dont know, what is the right maximum compression point. I found example, when i have 176 x 176 x 1 (~30976), then the point is 22 x 22 x 512 (~247808).

But how is that calculated?

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#Decoder
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse' , metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out these aspects of a network is more art than mathematics. As such, we cannot define a constant compression point without properly analyzing the data, which is the reason why neural nets are used in the first place.

We can however intuitively consider what happens at every layer. For example, in an image colorization problem, it is better not to use too many pooling layers since that discards a huge amount of information. A max pooling layer of size 2x2 with a stride of 2 discards 75% of its input data. This is much more useful in classification to eliminate improbable classes. Similarly, ReLU discards all negative data, and may not be the best function choice for the problem at hand.

Here are a few tips that may help with your specific problem:

1. Reduce the number of pooling layers. Before pooling, try increasing the number of trainable layers so that the model (intuitively) learns to aggregate important information to avoid pooling it out.
2. Change the activation to `elu`, `LeakyReLU` or such, that do not eliminate negative values, especially since the output requires negative values as well.
3. Maybe try BiLinear or BiCubic upsampling to maintain structure? I'd also suggest taking a look at the so called "magic" kernel [here](https://viewer.mathworks.com/?viewer=plain_code&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fmlc-downloads%2Fdownloads%2Fsubmissions%2F40392%2Fversions%2F5%2Fcontents%2Fmagickernel%2Fmagickernel.m&embed=web). Personally, I've had good results with it, though it takes time to implement it efficiently.
4. If you have enough GPU space, increase the number of channels. This particular point does not have much to consider, except overfitting in some cases.
5. Preferably, use a `Conv2D` layer as the final layer to compensate for artifacts while upsampling.

Keep in mind that these points are for general use cases. Models in research papers are a different case, and are not as simple as your architecture. All these points may or may not apply to a specific paper.